# How do you log code line by line as it is running in python

Tags: python, selenium, logging

I need to be able to log each line of code as it is running in my console. currently using selenium python.

Update: this is not for debugging purposes, its for demo purposes.

Comment: Why? Do you have a problem with your code that you need to figure out? Doesn't it help by using a debugger to step through the code? Please [edit] your question to include the reasons behind this request.

Comment: Use a debugger. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html